# Manually run functions from a standalone script

Tags: security, button, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code for spreadsheet tasks in a standalone script (for security reasons).

But **I also need to have a button or a menu item or something to be able to run the script manually just in case.**

Right now it is not allowed to run the standalone code with a button.

What are the ways to do it and what would be the easiest way?

(don't want to add it as a library as the code will be visible in the debugger)

Comment: The only way to run code in a stand alone script without loading the code in the code editor is by using the published url, and making either a GET request to `doGet()` or a POST request to `doPost()`  There are various ways to make the requests.  A hyperlink can make a GET Request.  Or the user can paste/type the url in the browser address bar and refresh the page.  The GET request could return nothing, and run the code.  The GET request could show a simple HTML page, and then the user could click a button to run the code.  Client side code could make an XML HttpRequest.

Comment: Thank you. There are even no html elemens, just data population. But if it wasn't populated want to be able to do it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your have three paths to choose, publish your standalone script as

1. an add-on -> https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/overview
2. a web application -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
3. an API Executable -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute

Depending of the path that you choose and other implementation decisions you could have a menu, an image that works as a button or HTML Service dialog/sidebar to call the target function

Comment: Thank you! What's the fastest and easiest way here?

Comment: @kiki Maybe 2 or 3 as they doesn't require to configure a Cloud Project, publish and wait for the publishing process is done.

Comment: as for this API it says "You can use this method in a calling application to run a function in one of your script projects remotely"  - the calling application is a  page on the Google Cloud with control panel to manually run functions (likewise virtual machine or database cloud panels etc.)? Or what's the calling application exactly?

Comment: The calling application could be any application that is able to call REST APIs.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case some other platform needed. Web app would be simpler I think.